# Генерация PDF из MySQL(php5) как?

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, pdf

Как сгенерировать PDF из данных хранящихся в MySQL. Используя в PHP класс mysqli.
Пробовал старым классом mysql ,  большое количество примеров. Не один не помог.
Библиотеки которыми были попытки: FPDF и mPDF.
Сейчас роюсь в TCPDF положительный результат отсутствует.

```
    С классом mysql и библиотекой FPDF
    <?php
    require('font/helvetica.php');
    require('fpdf.php');

    $hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    $database = "test";
    $username = "admins";
    $password = "admins";
    $conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database, mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password));

    $pdf=new FPDF();

    $pdf->Open();

    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

    $pdf->AddPage();

    $y_axis_initial = 25;

    $pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
    $pdf->SetX(25);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Complaint', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Date', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Text', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Polar words', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Source', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Company id', 1, 0, 'R', 1);

    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oven1 ") or die(mysql_error());

    $i = 0;

    $max = 25;

    $row_height = 6;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    if ($i == $max)
    {
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
    $pdf->SetX(25);

    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Complaint', 1, 0, 'L', 1);

    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

    $i = 0;
    }

    $complainant = $row[atribut];
    $date = $row[id];


    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(25);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $complainant, 1, 0, 'L', 1);

    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $pdf->Output('report.pdf','F');


    ?>
```

Comment: У вас салат в вопросе!! MySQL - это база данных. Там хранятся данные и наверное они нужны для решения вашей задачи. PHP - это язык, на котором пишут серверную часть сайта или веб-приложения. С помощью серверного языка можно вытащить данные из базы данных. Тоесть только после того как эти данные у вас есть, вы сможете сгенерировать PDF. Теперь первый вопрос - вы данные из базы данных получили?

Comment: Генерации не происходит. Либо получаю ошибку с базой не соединяет, то пустой pdf(или пустые значения таблице)

Comment: раз у Вас есть проблема с получением данных из бд, может стоит повременить с попыткой создания pdf а сначала задать вопрос в котором привести пример как Вы пытаетесь работать с бд и какая ошибка у Вас возникает?!

Comment: до генерации pdf , выводится часть базы, с этим ошибки не связаны. Решение проблемы нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сгенерировал через библиотеку html2pdf рабочий пример ниже.

```
<?php
require_once('html2pdf.class.php');
ob_start();
function printResult ($result_set) {
while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) != false){
    global $age;
    echo '<table style="width: 100%; text-align: left; border=1">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 40%; text-align: left">'
    .$row[atribut].
    '</td><td style="width: 10%; text-align: left">'
    .$row[a1].
    '</td>
    </tr>
    </table>';
  }
}
$mysqli = new mysqli ("127.0.0.1", "root", "pass", "bd");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// Вывод значений
$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table ");
printResult ($result_set);
$mysqli->close ();

$content = ob_get_clean();
// Конвертируем в PDF
try
{
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('freesans');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
$html2pdf->Output('base.pdf');
}
catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 если я правильно понимаю через mysqli подключаться надо так `$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $database, $username, $password);-` это если с базой даных проблема.
если проблема с пустым PDF  при использовании TCPDF то насколько я помню для записи в PDF надо использовать метод writeHTML класса pdf  теесть примерно так

```
$pdf->writeHTML($yourVar, true, false, false, false, '');
```

где $yourVar это то что вам нужно записать в pdf фаил остальное это служебная информация  вот [здесь документация](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/annotated.html)